# How to specify two different subnets in NFS exportfs cluster resource on RHEL 7

Tags: redhat, nfs, cluster, pacemaker

I'm configuring a NFS export resource on a RHEL 7 cluster, and I need to let a shared directory be mountable from clients belonging to different subnetworks.

For example, the following command obviously works fine (with only one network defined):

```
pcs resource create TEST-EXPORTFS ocf:heartbeat:exportfs clientspec=192.168.1.0/24 options=rw,sync,no_root_squash directory=/test fsid=1
```

but how can I add a second network in the "clientspec" parameter (for example: 192.168.100.0/24) so clients from both subnets can mount the shared directory?

I haven't been able to find any help in the official documentation (neither from RedHat nor from Linux-HA).

Thanks in advance for any precious help.

Comment: what about **clientspec="192.168.1.0/24 192.168.100.0/24"***

Comment: This is the first thing I tried... syntax error is all we get... :(

`>  stderr: INFO: Directory /test is not exported to 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.100.0/24 (stopped).
>  stderr: INFO: Exporting file system ...
>  stderr: ERROR: exportfs: Invalid export syntax: 192.168.1.0/24 exporting 192.168.100.0/24:/temp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its an older question but its in the top 10 on a google search so I thought I'd answer with what worked for me in case anyone else hits this looking for the same thing

I had a similar issue where I have a lot of servers so I have them split up by subnets based on what they do and needed to export some dirs only to 1 subnet or the other and some to all the subnets and I discovered a neat little trick thats un documented. you simply add 2 seperate resources each with the subnet you need and same fsid then you will see that it exports it once with both subnets

example:

```
[root@nas1 ~]# pcs resource create nfs-log1 exportfs clientspec=192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 options=rw,sync,no_root_squash directory=/mnt/nfsshare/logdata fsid=2 --group nfsgroup
[root@nas1 ~]# pcs resource create nfs-log2 exportfs clientspec=172.16.0.0/255.255.255.0 options=rw,sync,no_root_squash directory=/mnt/nfsshare/logdata fsid=2 --group nfsgroup
```

then a showmount will return like this:

```
/mnt/nfsshare/logdata 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0,172.16.0.0/255.255.255.0
```